# Updating position based on id

Tags: mysql

Here is how my table looks like

```
id|position | name  
1 | 4       | a
1 | 2       | b
1 | 3       | c
1 | 1       | d
23| 5       | a
23| 1       | b
24| 1       | a
```

Here is what I want :

```
id|position| name
1 | 1      | a
1 | 2      | b
1 | 3      | c
1 | 4      | d
23| 1      | a
23| 5      | b
24| 1      | a
```

Currently my SQL query displays the id and name in ascending order like so:

```
ORDER BY id, name
```

(Means it arranges the id first and THEN the name)

However, I want to **RE-ASSIGN** **/ OVER_WRITE**/**UPDATE** position values. So, for one id (which have many names) , i want to assign the position number in the ascending order of names.

I hope my question was clear.

Comment: This feels to me like you are trying to break the relational data in your table.  Could you come up with a better design?

Comment: I want to over write the position values. can i do that?

Comment: Please clarify: are you trying to accomplish this *visually* in a `SELECT` statement or *actually change the values in the table* through an `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: @Indigo Please review my updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` query to create a new table called `newtable` from the result of a query:

```
INSERT INTO newtable (id, position, name)
SELECT t1.id AS id, t1.position AS position, t2.name AS name
FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC, position ASC
) t1,
(
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC, name ASC
) t2
```

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to UPDATE not SELECT :(

Comment: I `UPDATE`d my answer (no pun intended).  Try using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to create a new table.

Answer (score 0):

```
update TABLENAME left join  
    (select tp1.id,tp1.name,tp2.position from 
        (select t.*,(select count(*) from TABLENAME where name<t.name) as rownum from TABLENAME t order by id,name) tp1
        left join
        (select t.*,(select count(*) from TABLENAME where position<t.position) as rownum from TABLENAME t order by id,position) tp2
        on tp1.rownum = tp2.rownum
    ) as tmp 
on TABLENAME.id=tmp.id and TABLENAME.name=tmp.name  set TABLENAME.position=tmp.position ;
```

If the table has some unique columns besides the columns you have showed,you can replace the `rownum` with a unique column. Now I use the `count(*)` with `name` to generate a unique column.

In addition,this sql script may get the result,but it works in poor performing.